# indexOf for array with different objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, indexof

I have an array of users.

When I click on button "Add New", I want to add new object to this array only if it doen't exist there:

```
var newUser = { 'creating': true, 'editMode': true };
if ($scope.users.indexOf(newUser) < 0) {
    $scope.users.push(newUser);
}
```

but `indexOf` always return `-1`.

Is this because array contain "different" objects?

[image]

Comment: you need to identify the user with a different approach, like check with id. if `newUser` is not *the same object*, the you get always `-1`

Comment: two different objects can't be equal.

Comment: `Array.prototype.findIndex()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose each time you're going to call "Add New", it'll work (hard to say without more code). For the simple reason that each instance of `newUser` is a different one.

The `indexOf` calls check for exactly this instance of `newUser`. It doesn't check the property values, just for the reference to the instance.

e.g. :

```
var user = {a : "b"};
var users = [];
users.push(user);
users.indexOf(user); // returns 0, reference the user created at the top, inserted beforehand
user = {a : "b"};
users.indexOf(user); // returns -1, reference the user created just above, not yet inserted
```

If you want to check for instance, you'll have to make a check on a property (name, id, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a *collection of unique values* you should use [`ECMASCRIPT-6 Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

If you need to stay legacy, otherwise, you need to use arrays...

```js
var Set = (function() {
  function Set() {}
  
  Set.prototype.has = function(val) {
    return !!this._list.filter(i => i.id === val.id).length;
  };
  
  Set.prototype.get = function(val) {
    if(!val) {
      return this._list;
    }
    
    return this._list.filter(i => i.id === val.id).pop();
  };
  
  Set.prototype.add = function(val) {
    if(!this.has(val)) {
      this._list.push(val)
    }
    
    return this;
  }
  
  return Set;
})();
```